# given: ifstream infile("test.txt") is there advantage to use if(!infile)... versus if(infile.good())...?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I came across this code in my reading:

```
void assure(std::ifstream& infile ) {  
  if(!infile) { /* stuff */}
}
```

I tested for curiosity using function argument types `ifstream&` and `ifstream`,  and it seems to work.  I was curious how the conditional expression might work.  Is this a case of NULL object or empty object?  I thought C++ object could not be NULL?

Since `!infile` works, how is a failed `ifstream` object represented?

Thanks for the ensuing enlightenment.

Comment: You might be interested to know that `operator!` is overloaded for this object: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_not/

Comment: This function is taking its argument by *reference*, not by *pointer*.  So NULL doesn't come into it.

Comment: Thanks.  I read your recommended link, and it cleared up the mystery for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the [negate operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_not/), and it is simply hooked to the `fail()` check.

It's not entirely the opposite of `good()`, as that one also checks for EOF (`eofbit`).

(And yes, a reference always points to an object, the question is meaningless, only a pointer can be NULL).

Answer (score 0):

It won't make any great difference, no. Both will result in very similar code the same behaviour. The difference is in the behaviour on `eof`, which `good` will return `false` for, where `operator!` sees that as a `true`. However, this makes little difference in most cases, as the `failbit` will be set in the `fstream` state if an attempt to read past the end of file is made - there are some cases when this doesn't happen, but most of the time, it's the same thing.